# Software: Excel VBA Not Populating Default File Name in SaveAs Dialog Box

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I am having an issue with some VBA code in my master Excel workbook. I have two pieces of code. Code A Works fine. Code B does not work fine.

The first piece of code (Code A), which works fine, creates a directory and saves the Excel Workbook in it, with the name of both the directory and the file being pulled from a cell B4.

The second piece of code (Code B) goes to a directory and opens a save as dialog box, and is supposed to fill the initial file name box with information from cell B4. However, everything works except the initial filename does not autofill. It used to; it was working just before I changed all the macro references for the mapped drives (I changed them from the mapped letter drives to the UNC pathway so the file can be used on the network, i.e. Z:\In Progress\ to \10.0.0.4\data\In Progress).

The odd thing is, I am not having any issues accessing the network after changing from mapped drive -> UNC pathways. It just appears to be this little glitch.

I have compiled the project and debugged it.

If anyone has an idea on how to populate the initial file name for Code B, it would be much appreciated.

CODE A

```
    Option Explicit
Sub SaveAsNewJobtoIP()
'This macro creates a New Folder in the In Progress File, named off the BILLING CLIENT Name.
Dim Path As String
Dim InitialName As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant

    Path = "\\10.0.0.4\data\In Progress\"

        If Len(Dir("\\10.0.0.4\data\In Progress\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir Path & ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value
        End If

'This macro saves the workbook with a Dialog and an Initial Filename
    InitialName = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("H2") & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("I2") & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("J2")
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Path & InitialName, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If sFileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
    End If
End Sub
```

CODE B

```
    Option Explicit
Sub SaveAsNewQuoteinJCF()
'This macro saves the workbook with a Dialog and an Initial Filename
Dim Path As String
Dim InitialName As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant

    Path = "\\10.0.0.4\data\Job Cost Folder\Jill\"
    InitialName = "Estimate " & ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Path & InitialName, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If sFileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: " Z:\In Progress\ to \10.0.0.4\data\In Progress)." - Directories cannot have periods in them.  My first guess is that your directory in this case isn't valid.  You can use the name of the share (i.e. \\MyDrobo\\) where MyDrobo would resolve to `10.0.0.4`.  Except for the if clause I don't see any difference between the two code blocks.

Comment: "Directories cannot have periods in them."  There must be more to it than that absolute prohibition. This made me curious so I hopped to a CMD prompt, told Win7 to MD This.Is.My.Directory  No error messages occurred, but DIR shows the new directory, as does WinExplorer when I START .    Some of the Win UI features obsessively(stupidly) observe the FileExplorer option of hiding file extensions. I suspect there'd be trouble sooner or later if you have directory names that include periods if this option is enabled. Other thoughts?

Comment: It does look like `GetSaveAsFilename` has problems with periods as a folder name as @Ramhound suggested. Try changing your path to `C:\folder.with.periods\Estimate` and you will see that the file name box is also blank.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Do all the in File Explorer, command prompt, never had the path 255 character limits neither (to my knowledge)

Comment: @Ramhound Having difficulty parsing that last.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - I know you did, because the limitation is in File Explorer, which is what the Save As dialog is based on.  The command prompt wouldn't have a problem with it, that is to be expected, due to various differences between the command prompt and File Explorer.  I said, navigate to that directory, using File Explorer.  *You won't be able to, a folder with a period will likely be displayed as a file not a folder.*  I was saying that File Explorer had the 255 character path limits, and if you were to navigate to the same path within a command prompt, you would be able to.

Comment: @Ramhound Just tried this again; after creating (via command prompt) a directory called c:\temp\this.is.my.dir I was able to start Notepad, save a file to it, close notepad, navigate to it in File Explorer, open the file, etc. So apparently in Win7/64, there's no problem with directory.names.that.include.periods   I'm not near my other machines that have other versions of Windows installed so can't test to see if we're seeing different things due to Win version differences.

Comment: Another issue you may be running into is not explicitly stating the file format. What is in your cell B4?

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of research and trying to figure out my local network's landscape, but I figured out with help of comments that all I had to do to fix the issue was:

Replace the UNC Pathway with the Actual Name of the Computer.
So I changed

```
"\\10.0.0.4\" ---> "\\Server-pc\"
```

and the problem was solved. I thought the 10.0.0.4 was the Server computer's name, but it was actually just a pathway. Changing from the UNC Pathway to the actual computer's name also solved another issue where macros were receiving Run-time errors (1004) because my coworker's UNC Pathway was actually 10.0.0.3.